# How to add discussion comments to the existing workitem card(Feature card) through API in Azure DevOps

Tags: api, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to add discussion comments that is [System.History] to the existing card. How can I do it through API or is there any update WIQL query to update the card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the REST API. See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/comments/add?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1. As of 22.07.2020 the documentation there is still incorrect, see https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/issues/313.

Sample Request (HTTP)

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/fabrikam/Fabrikam-Fiber-Git/_apis/wit/workItems/299/comments?api-version=5.1-preview.3
```

Request Body (JSON)

```
{
  "text": "Moving to the right area path"
}
```

Comment: i have tried this it won't work, getting the error as "{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"You must provide a value for the text parameter.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssPropertyValidationException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common","typeKey":"VssPropertyValidationException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}"

Comment: As the error message says: your parameter `text` in the request body is empty.

Comment: i have passed the text message in parameter post still i am getting the same error

Comment: Which tool or programming language are you using to call the REST API?

Comment: I am calling it from AA, i figured it out the issue from one of the post , the request body should not contain [], it should be {
    "text": "Moving to the right area path"
  }

Comment: Okay, there's a bug in the documentation (see https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-rest-api-specs/issues/313)